# Recyclerview in scrollview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-scrollview

This is the code :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/grey_f2"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    >
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/rv_achievement_badges"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"

        />
    <LinearLayout
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="25dp"
        >
        <com.sharesmile.share.views.LBTextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/hall_of_fame"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:textColor="@color/black_64"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            />
        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/rv_hall_of_fame"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

The issue is `rv_hall_of_fame` does not show all items. 
tried nestedsrollview, viewport, canScrollVertically and setNestedScrollingEnabled and nothing is working. Can you let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove the second recyclerview from the linearlayout. Maybe that is the reason you can't see all items.

EDIT:

I think you should use NestedScrollView. I had the same problem in one of my projects and I changed my code to below which solved my problem.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/grey_f2"
android:fillViewport="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/rv_achievement_badges"/>

<com.sharesmile.share.views.LBTextView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/hall_of_fame"
android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
android:textColor="@color/black_64"
android:textSize="20sp"
android:background="@color/white"
android:paddingLeft="25dp"
android:paddingTop="36dp"/>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/rv_hall_of_fame"
android:background="@color/white"
android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
android:paddingBottom="30dp"
android:paddingTop="30dp"
android:paddingLeft="25dp"
android:paddingRight="25dp"/>

</LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: @ParthAnjaria I have updated my answer, Please check.

Comment: Thanks, works like a charm. so simple and i wasted one day on it

Answer (score 0):

It's not wise to put a `RecyclerView` or a `ListView` inside a `ScrollView`. Android doesn't know how to handle user events. In addition, in your case, you have two `RecyclerView` inside that root `ScrollView`... It's madness both for the Android UI framework and for the user.

A solution could be to only use one `RecyclerView` that handles the scroll user action, and an `Adapter` that knows how to render everything you use: achievements badges, the hall of fame label, and the players. So, you'll only need one `RecyclerView`, and it will work like a charm.